# Does hide mean to make disappear

Tags: grammar

Someone asked me

What if someone hides their instagram stories from you?

I replied
I'd hide them from my life

Is my sentence right

Does hide mean to make disappear?

If not
What else could I have used here?

Object of preposition from can not be a place like the magician hid(made her disappear) from the stage?